# Executing sql from datatable row

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I have table with some sql queries that is executed from application. 
for example, one of query with id=1 is:

```
select * from customer where status='A'
```

What I want is to do some replace in that query and return rows of that executed query. I want to do everything that in sql.
For example, if I say

```
select id, query from queries where id=1
```

I will get result:

1 | select * from customer where status='A'

If I say:

select id, replace(query, 'A', 'N') from queries where id=1

I will get:

1 | select * from customer where status='N'

I want to execute this replaced query and see result for it.
Is that possible to do just with sql?
I am using oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but this is what I can think of now:
create a pipeline function that will return you a table type of desired kind of record.
Then just call it as:

```
select * from table(your_function(parm1, parm2, parm3));
```

where as parameters you will give all the info you need to replace text in the base query like query id, string to search, string to replace, etc. In the function, you will take the query from the table, replace the placeholders, execute it and pipe out rows.
Or even write a query that will get exact query statement as a varchar/clob and just execute it 'as is' and pipe out the rows to the caller.

this will explain you pipelined functions in a simple example:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions